# How to update NULL values?

Tags: mysql

I have added ENUM column in my table, and all my rows that are already existing have got a NULL value. The only problem is that I don't get how to select and upgrade them to what I need.

I've tried something like `UPGRADE users Status='User' where Status=NULL` and other options like "`... where Status=''` " but none of these bring me the solution.

I want to change every NULL value to 'User'.

Comment: Is `'User'` one of the enumerated values? If it is then do an UPDATE.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

NULL is a special value, in pretty much any normal comparison, if NULL is involved the result is NULL; which is not TRUE, which means effectively FALSE. When comparing for NULL you need to is `x IS NULL`, or `x IS NOT NULL`.

That said, I generally recommend avoiding MySQL's ENUM data type. Adding new values involves ALTER TABLE, which involves rebuilding the table. They also do not "play nice" with a lot of libraries used to connect to databases; and have weird semantic in general. You're usually much better off with a lookup table using standard data types.

Also, the statement type you're looking for is `UPDATE`, there is no "UPGRADE".

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
UPDATE users
SET    Status = 'User'
WHERE  Status IS NULL;
```

This is because NULL is a special value. Conceptually, NULL means “a missing unknown value” and it is treated somewhat differently from other values. To test for NULL, use the `IS NULL` and `IS NOT NULL` operators.